# Dictionary integer as key and function as value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary

This is my code:

```
def test1():
  print("nr1")

def test2():
  print("nr2")

def test3():
  print("nr3")

def main():
  dictionary = { 1: test1(), 2: test2(), 3: test3() }
  dictionary[2]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This code returns:

```
nr1
nr2
nr3
```

What do I need to change in the code to get this:

```
nr2
```

I'm using Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't call the functions inside the dict; call the result of the dict lookup.

```
dictionary = { 1: test1, 2: test2, 3: test3 }
dictionary[2]()
```

Answer (score 3):

Omit the function calls when creating the dictionary and just call what `dictionary[2]` returns:

```
def main():
  dictionary = { 1: test1, 2: test2, 3: test3 }
  dictionary[2]()
```

Answer (score 3):

The line below actually calls each function and stores the *result* in the dictionary:

```
dictionary = { 1: test1(), 2: test2(), 3: test3() }
```

This is why you see the three lines of output.  Each function is being called.  Since the functions have no return value, the value `None` is stored in the dictionary.  Print it (`print(dictionary`):

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Instead, store the function itself in the dictionary:

```
dictionary = { 1: test1, 2: test2, 3: test3 }
```

Result of `print(dictionary)`:

```
{1: <function test1 at 0x000000000634D488>, 2: <function test2 at 0x000000000634D510>, 3: <function test3 at 0x000000000634D598>}
```

Then use a dictionary lookup to get the function, and *then* call it:

```
dictionary[2]()
```